# Troubleshooting optimization-related Swift compiler errors

Tags: xcode, swift, optimization

I have quite large Swift project which has been in development since the early versions of language. At these early stages of Swift development optimizations were unstable and caused troubles, so the decision was made to turn them off (optimization level was set to `-Onone`).

Now that Swift has matured, it's time to try turning optimizations back on. Unfortunately, after setting optimization level to `-O (fastest)` the project does not compile:

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

-------

Bitcast requires both operands to be pointer or neither
  %111 = bitcast %CSo19NSMutableURLRequest* %110 to i64, !dbg !44642
Bitcast requires both operands to be pointer or neither
  %144 = bitcast %CSo19NSMutableURLRequest* %143 to i64, !dbg !44642
Bitcast requires both operands to be pointer or neither
  %275 = bitcast %CSo19NSMutableURLRequest* %274 to i64, !dbg !44642
LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
```

I found several questions regarding the same kind of problem, but in all of them possible source of problem is pinpointed at least to a file.

How do I find the code which causes this problem (or at least the containing file)? Are there any strategies/approaches for that? And the most important question - is it worth the effort?

Comment: Search for "bitcast" in your project. Why are you using bitcast anyways? That's a horrible function and against the nature of Swift's typesafety!

Comment: @Kametrixom I don't use bitcast anywhere in my project :) Maybe one of the libraries uses it, but it's unlikely.

Comment: Oh sorry, the error message was just really pointing that way. You can always try to remove more and more parts of your code to find out when it compiles. Maybe it would've been better in your case if you turned optimizations on from the beginning, as it would immediately not compile when you add the certain piece of code that crashes it.

Comment: @Kametrixom I guess I'll have to resort to backtracking, but I was hoping there's a better approach.

Comment: Is the info any better if you build from command line? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2339/_index.html